# How do I reduce duplication by moving method to base class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, inheritance

I have this class.

```
public class ComponentMapper : MapperBase
{
    public static PageComponent Map(object value)
    {
        return value switch
        {
   
            _ => HandleUnknownType(value),
        };
    }

    private static HandleUnknownType(object value)
    {

            throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(ComponentMapper)} - failed to map object of type {value.GetType()}. Component={nameof(value)}");

    }
}
```

The `HandleUnknownType` is quite similar for all implementations, which is why I am considering moving it to the base class, `MapperBase`, problem is though that `nameof(ComponentMapper)` is used to state that the class that uses this function does know the type.

But if I move it to the base class, I will not be able to know the class that is implementing it.

I would like the `HandleUnknownType` method to stay static, to avoid creating uneeded objects

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: If you dont need the method HandleUnknownType to be static you can use this.GetType().Name and put the method in the base class.

Comment: True that was also an option, but since the rest is static I thought it would make sense to keep the rest static -  and don't create an unessesary object for all mapper classes I would need.

Comment: A Singleton Pattern for your Mapper might help if you fear creating objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this is via the ["Curiously recurring template pattern"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern), but it is not without drawbacks.

To do that you'd change the base class to be generic, where the generic type is constrained to itself, like so:

```
public abstract class MapperBase<TMapper, TComponent> where TMapper: MapperBase<TMapper, TComponent>
{
    protected static TComponent HandleUnknownType(object value)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException($"{typeof(TMapper).Name} - failed to map object of type {value.GetType()}. Component={nameof(value)}");
    }
}
```

Note that this also uses a type argument, `TComponent`, for the type to be returned from `HandleUnknownType()`.

With that, all your classes that derive from `MapperBase<TMapper, TComponent>` will have to repeat the pattern, like so:

```
public class PageMapper : MapperBase<PageMapper, PageComponent>
{
    public static PageComponent Map(object value)
    {
        return value switch
        {
            _ => HandleUnknownType(value)
        };
    }
}

public class OtherMapper : MapperBase<OtherMapper, OtherComponent>
{
    public static OtherComponent Map(object value)
    {
        return value switch
        {
            _ => HandleUnknownType(value)
        };
    }
}
```

Given that code, then calls to the static method `MapperBase.HandleUnknownType()` will output the correct exception message:

```
public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            PageMapper.Map("test");
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // PageMapper - failed to map object of type System.String. Component=value
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }

        try
        {
            OtherMapper.Map("test");
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // OtherMapper - failed to map object of type System.String. Component=value
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
}

public class PageComponent  {}
public class OtherComponent {}
```

[Try it on DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/40oA3J)

As I said, this is not without drawbacks. For example, there's nothing stopping the programmer from messing it up by specifying a different generic type than the class being declared, for example:

```
public class SomeOtherMapper : MapperBase<PageMapper, PageComponent> // WRONG!
{
}
```

Comment: But i still need to make a custom `HandleUnknownType` for every type of mapper - that does not return a Pagecomponent for instance?

I like the approach though :)

Comment: @IamnotFat It's hard to tell from your question how you intend to use `HandleUnknownType()`, given that you didn't give it a return type...

Comment: That is true since all of them inherits mapperbase, I would assume that only return type that is valid for all implementations would be mapperbase?

Comment: @IamnotFat I've extended the example to include specifying the return type of `HandleUnknownType()`.